# I copied a file into my VM, but the folder is a regular file

Tags: cp, cd-command

I'm new to Linux, and I'm trying to untar the following file, so I moved from GCS to the Virtual Machine with the following command

`gsutil cp gs://ghtorrent_datadump/mysql-2020-07-17.tar home/ghtorrent`

but now when I want to use

```
tar -xvf ghtorrent/mysql-2020-07-17.tar
```

I get tar: ghtorrent/mysql-2020-07-17.tar: Cannot open: Not a directory

Looking for an explanation I found that ghtorrent is a regular file instead of a directory

```
pablo_racana@untarfiles:~/home$ ls -ld ghtorrent
-rw-r--r-- 1 pablo_racana pablo_racana 478100428800 Aug 18 15:19 ghtorrent
```

what did I did wrong? should have specified **home/ghtorrent/** as destination directory?
Is there something that I can do to not lose the progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the folder is a regular file

There's no folder. I've no idea how this utility works but it didn't find the directory `home/ghtorrent` and it seemingly assumed it's your destination filename so your `mysql-2020-07-17.tar` file was uploaded as `ghtorrent` which you can simply untar:

```
tar -xvf home/ghtorrent
```

> should have specified home/ghtorrent/ as destination directory? Is there something that I can do to not lose the progress?

Perhaps you should have created this directory prior to running the upload command.

Comment: I used to do this all of the time.  `cp file ~/dir` will copy the file as `~/dir` if `~/dir` does not exist yet.  It will not `mkdir ~/dir && cp file ~/dir/file`.   To avoid this, I always trail directories with a `/`.  In this case `cp file ~/dir/`.  It makes it clear to us AND `cp` that `~/dir` should exist as a directory.  `cp` will fail if it doesn't.  This also works for similar tools like `scp`.

Comment: `cp`, `scp` and `gsutil` are all different utilities and they may follow different conventions. :-) Again, if you had created the `ghtorrent` directory in advance you could have got different results. I'm positively sure it did not exist prior to running the command.

Answer (score 2):

You have renamed the file as part of the copy, and it's now called `~/home/ghtorrent`.

```
cd ~/home/
mv ghtorrent mysql-2020-07-17.tar
mkdir ghtorrent
mv mysql-2020-07-17.tar ghtorrent/
tar -xvf ghtorrent/mysql-2020-07-17.tar
```

Next time you should create the destination directory first if that's what you want (`mkdir ghtorrent`).